# Azure configuration change without instance being tore down

Tags: c#, azure

I'm new to Azure (2.2) and am trying to workout configuration changes.  I have a flag in the azure config I would like to use.  In particular, to stop processing from queues, and help with staging vs production migrations.

I've uploaded the new configuration from config in the portal but after playing with this for a few hours, it appears it always destroys and recreates the instances.

Is there anyway to update the configuration file without the instance being destroyed?

Thanks

*** Edits and answers to responses ***

I did play with the changed/changing events.  They seemed as if they did run it was wiped out by the reboot.

My test, and I hope I explain my self well enough, but if you have a static counter variable and you default it to 1 and inside the changing/changing events and increment the variable every time the event fires.  I also set a static variable that was defaulted to "JUNK" to the new configuration value set in the event.   The results after uploading the configuration numerous times with numerous values and comparing the statics to what was read directly from the configuration were always the statics were back to default values and the new configuration flag was read.  The app domain was rebooted and all initialization code is ran again.  This means I could just ignore the setting change events and upload the configuration and let the initialization happen again which is what I was trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think its possible.  The configuration changes I needed to make always restarts the instance.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think role instances are destroyed and recreated when you change a configuration setting value. The role instance may be taken down to apply that setting and brought back up (in other words rebooted). If you're running more than one instance, the changes are applied on one instance at a time so that your application keeps working.

[`RoleEnvironment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.aspx) class has a [`Changing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.changing.aspx) event which can be used for that purpose. Do take a look at that. I believe if you set the `Cancel` property as `false`, the changes are applied without instances being taken down.

From the [`Changing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.changing.aspx) event documentation page:

> The Changing event and the Changed event are used together to identify
>   and manage configuration changes to the service model. By using the
>   Changing event, an instance can respond to a configuration change in
>   one of the following ways:
>
> - Accept the configuration change while it is running, without going offline.
> - Set the Cancel property of RoleEnvironmentChangingEventArgs to true to take the instance offline, apply the configuration change, and then
>     bring the instance back online.
>
> By using the Cancel property, you can ensure that the instance
>   proceeds through an orderly shutdown sequence and is taken offline
>   before the configuration change is applied. During the shutdown
>   process, Windows Azure raises the Stopping event, and then runs any
>   code in the OnStop method.

Comment: Maybe the cancel property is what i need to play with.

Answer (score 1):

If your settings are in the ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file, you can simply update the config settings in the Azure Portal.  Browse to the cloud service and select the CONFIGURE tab.  Scroll down to SETTINGS - change the value and then save.

Comment: Maybe my configuration flag setup is wrong because it does not show up in the portal directly.  Only Azure configurations like connection strings and bus stuff ect.